# Python websockets client keep connection open

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, python-asyncio

In Python, I'm using "[websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)" library for websocket client.

```
import asyncio
import websockets

async def init_sma_ws():
    uri = "wss://echo.websocket.org/"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send('name')
        greeting = await websocket.recv()
```

The problem is the client websocket connection is disconnected once a response is received. I want the connection to remain open so that I can send and receive messages later.

What changes do I need to keep the websocket open and be able to send and receive messages later?

Answer (score 4):

I think your websocket is disconnected due to exit from context manager after `recv()`.
Such code works perfectly:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def init_sma_ws():
    uri = "wss://echo.websocket.org/"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            name = input("What's your name? ")
            if name == 'exit':
                break

            await websocket.send(name)
            print('Response:', await websocket.recv())


asyncio.run(init_sma_ws())
```

Answer (score -1):

In your approach you used a asynchronous context manager which closes a connection when code in the block is executed. In the example below an infinite asynchronous iterator is used which keeps the connection open.

```py
import asyncio
import websockets


async def main():
    async for websocket in websockets.connect(...):
        try:
            ...
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            continue


asyncio.run(main())
```

More info in [library's docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/client.html#opening-a-connection).